# Форматирование копированного текста | JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть текст с разными стилями (bold, italic, link и т.п.). Мне необходимо скопировать текст так, чтобы сохранились все стили при вставке где-то внутри ресура, но но потерялись вне.

Пример текста:

**Ссылка на документ:** https://google.com, не забудьте прислать ответ на почту: *google@gmail.com*

При копировании **ВНУТРИ** ресура, должны сохраниться все стили и т.п., но когда я вставляю этот же текст, к примеру, в поисковик гугла, все стили должны исчезнуть. Знает ли кто-то, как подобное реализовывают?

Comment: вставка в `textarea` или в какой элемент? как вариант можно сделать кнопочку копирования (есть на многих сайтах где представлены снипеты) например [тут](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vue) можно скопировать тремя способами

Comment: Вкратце, на копировании (Событие `copy`), берём копированный текст (`document.getSelection()`), перезаписываем с учётом элементов `navigator.clipboard.writeText`, и когда пользователь уходит с вкладки (События `blur` и `beforeunload`) перезаписываем без учёта элементов.

Comment: @NNL993, звучит интересно.